# Is the Kähler cone of a toric variety always simplicial?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, toric-varieties

I am working on a familly of toric varieties which seem to have the following property:

- the closure of the Kähler cone is a **simplicial** cone (and even a smooth cone with respect to the natural lattice).

This has the interesting aspect that it provides a natural basis of the $H^2$ cohomology group.

I was wondering whether this is or not a trivial property.

> Is the closed Kähler cone of any smooth toric variety a simplicial cone ?

I would guess that the answer is no, but I do not know a counter-example.

It is known that this cone is polyhedral for all toric varieties. But maybe one can find examples where it has more generators ? Do you know one ?

Comment: Perhaps you are thinking of the *pseudoeffective* cone.

Comment: Could you tell me the definition of a *simplicial cone*? Thanks

Comment: A simplicial cone is a cone of dimension d with d rays.  for some integer d.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Kähler cone of a del Pezzo surface of degree 6 is not simplicial: see section 6 of [these notes](http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/daviesr/resources/notes/dP6.pdf).